# Fitting non-normpdf's to histograms in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

I'm trying to do a fit to a histogram but without any luck. There's a bunch of information about how to do it in a normal probability density function but not to other types of pdf's.

```
import pylab as py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import exponpow

# Fit procedure
eigfit=[]
for i in range(0,len(eigenvals1)):
if eigenvals1>=4.3:
    eigfit.append(eigenvals1[i])

b = exponpow.fit(eigfit)
```

But I cannot find how to plot the curve for this exponential pdf. It gives me a couple of values from the fit, but in scipy docs it's not well explained how it does this fit.

Comment: is the problem getting numbers out of the fit or plotting the fit once you have it?

Answer (score 4):

The `fit` method does a [maximum likelihood estimation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood) of the parameters.

To fit an `exponpow` distribution, you probably want the location parameter (that all scipy distributions have) to be 0.  There are two other parameters: a scale parameter and a shape parameter.  Here's an example (in an ipython session) of using  `exponpow.fit`, with the location parameter fixed at 0:

First generate some fake data:

```
In [108]: np.random.seed(123)

In [109]: samples = 5 + np.random.randn(1000)
```

Use `exponpow.fit` to fit the parameters to the data.  Use `floc=0` to fix the location parameter to 0:

```
In [110]: params = exponpow.fit(samples, floc=0)
```

Plot a histogram of the samples, using `matplotlib.pyplot.hist`:

```
In [111]: histresult = hist(samples, density=True, facecolor='cyan', alpha=0.25)
```

Plot the PDF of the fitted distribution, using the method `exponpow.pdf`:

```
In [112]: x = np.linspace(0, samples.max() + 1, 100)

In [113]: pdf = exponpow.pdf(x, *params)

In [114]: plot(x, pdf, 'b-', linewidth=2)
Out[114]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x5b59b90>]
```

These are the values of the fitted parameters (shape, loc, scale):

```
In [115]: params
Out[115]: (3.5192555959521199, 0, 6.078044809594477)
```

[image: plot]