# Fitting distribution with fixed parameters in SciPy

Tags: python, scipy, distribution, exponential, data-fitting

Is it possible to fix parameters while fitting distributions in SciPy? For example, this code:

```
import scipy.stats as st
xx = st.expon.rvs(size=100)
print st.expon.fit(xx, loc=0)
```

results in non-zero location (`loc`).

When some parameter is provided to the `fit` function it is considered as an initial guess. And if it is provided to the constructor (`st.expon(loc=0)`) the distribution becomes "frozen" and can not be used for fitting.

Comment: Please elaborate on your question.

Comment: the question is clear

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To fix `loc`, use the argument `floc`:

```
print st.expon.fit(xx, floc=0)
```

E.g.

```
In [33]: import scipy.stats as st

In [34]: xx = st.expon.rvs(size=100)

In [35]: print(st.expon.fit(xx, floc=0))
(0, 0.77853895325584932)
```

Some related questions:

- [Gamma distribution fit error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18190426/gamma-distribution-fit-error/18192200)
- [Why does the Gamma distribution in SciPy have three parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16963415/why-does-the-gamma-distribution-in-scipy-have-three-parameters/16964743)
- [Fitting non-normpdf's to histograms in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20573108/fitting-non-normpdfs-to-histograms-in-matplotlib/20575960)