# scipy.stats.expon.fit() with no location parameter

Tags: python, scipy, statsmodels

I am using `scipy.stats.expon.fit(data)`  to fit an exponential distribution to my data. This appears to return two values where I would expect one.  The documentation [online](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.expon.html) doesn't seem to say what `fit()` returns but looking at the source, I am guessing it is both a location and scale parameter. Can you fix the location parameter to `0` when doing the fitting?

Comment: @mdml Thank you. I would like to run fit but have the location fixed to 0. It seems this isn't the default behaviour. (It is odd that it has a location parameter at all to be honest for the exponential distribution.)

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21610034/fitting-distribution-with-fixed-parameters-in-scipy/  (Yeah, I know I already answered. Shame on me.)

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Ah well I will happily delete it but it would be great if the docs could be updated!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In the call to `expon.fit`, use `floc=0`:

```
In [5]: data = expon.rvs(0, 1.5, 1000)

In [6]: loc, scale = expon.fit(data, floc=0)

In [7]: scale
Out[7]: 1.4878030368336586

In [8]: loc
Out[8]: 0
```

Comment: Thank you! Is that in the documentation anywhere? Or in other words, how did you know this?

Comment: You have to read the docstring of `expon.fit` pretty closely to find it, but it is mentioned in there.  Read the description of `kwds` in the "Parameters" section.

Comment: Oh wow. The official web page has loads less information in it than the docstring!!