# Scipy: What's the difference between fit using loc=0, floc=0?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

As I'm fitting a Weibull distribution, and also find in other questions as [Fitting distribution with fixed parameters in SciPy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21610034/fitting-distribution-with-fixed-parameters-in-scipy)

There is a difference between fit using `floc=0`, and `loc=0`

```
weibull_params = 1, 2.0755160030790547, 0, 16.273031221223277
data = sp.stats.exponweib.rvs(*weibull_params, size=50000)
data = data.astype(int)
x = linspace(0, 55)

weibull_params1 = sp.stats.weibull_min.fit(data)
weibull_params2 = sp.stats.weibull_min.fit(data, loc=0)
weibull_params3 = sp.stats.weibull_min.fit(data, floc=0)

for weibull_params, line_style in zip([weibull_params1, weibull_params2, weibull_params3],['-','--','-.']):
    plt.figure()
    plt.hist(data, bins=arange(0,55),alpha=0.5, normed=True)
    y_weibull = sp.stats.weibull_min.pdf(x, *weibull_params)
    plot(x, y_weibull, line_style, color='black') 
    print(weibull_params)
```

would produce the Weibull like these:

[image]

Weibull params:

```
(0.50240047370945606, -4.501644985259555e-28, 2.9918077253782287)
(2.0610053128948245, -0.45099484072568979, 16.299110670854041) #loc=0
(1.0, 0, 1.05) #floc=0
```

What is the difference? When should I use which one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is: `floc` (and `fscale` for that matter) are used to specify that the location parameter (and scale parameter respectively) are to be kept fixed at the specified value. `loc` and `scale` merely give starting values for the fit.

`sp.stats.weibull_min` inherits the `fit` method from `scipy.stat.rv_continuous`. The [documentation of `scipy.stats.rv_continuous.fit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.fit.html#scipy.stats.rv_continuous.fit) specifies the fact, that `floc` and `fscale` keep said parameters fixed. `loc`, `scale` and other keyword arguments that are recognized by derived distributions are simply used as starting values.

So if you want to fit keeping the location fixed, you should use `floc=0` if you only want to provide a starting parameter, you should use `loc=0`.

Comment: So it seems like the fitting method for Weibull_min is not very good? As it is the result without `loc=0` is much worse than setting it as the initial value?